# In the compositor how do I export a video file - when I select FFmpeg as output, file export defaults to OPENEXR

Tags: compositing-nodes

So I've rendered out the files as a image stack but want to render it to a video file. I reimported the image stack into the compositor and added file output (changed the OUTPUT type to FFMPEG (as per manual) but when you pull out FILE OUTPUT in compositor it's now reading OPENEXR (?). I'm lost. Any help welcome.

Comment: Any particular reason you're importing them into the compositor and not into the video sequencer?

Comment: Not really  - I just like the nodal thing - it;s a pity you can't set the image output details in the node. I've since done it in the editor and managed to export a video file.

Comment: Once you import into the sequencer and get your settings down you can switch back to the compositor and enable nodes